# How to print spades, hearts, diamonds, etc. in C and Linux?

Tags: c, linux

So i started off by placing an array of char
char symbols[52] = { '\x03' , '\x04', etc. . etc.) 
and the first time I did it, it actually did print the hearts,spades, etc. but after changing my system locale to a korean one (idk if this is what caused it), it started giving me weird symbols that had nothing to do with it.
I also tried to do it in another computer and it actually compiled the symbols correctly.
However, then I tried moving it on to linux and it printed weird squares with a 0 0 0 3 in it.

Does anyone know why these appear or is there a better way to print these symbols?

P.S.: I'm using Visual Studio in Windows and then used the .c code in Linux

Comment: Does Visual Studio run on Linux? O_o

Comment: In Linux, there's really no reason to have your terminal not set to use UTF-8, so you can show all of Unicode regardless of your locale.

Comment: Oh no I meant in using visual studio in Windows, i then compiled the .c file in linux sorry mb!

Comment: Hmm is there a reason why in Visual Studio it actually shows the symbols but not in Linux though?

Comment: @Seung: The ROM for the IBM PC provided graphics for the ASCII control characters, so \x03 through \x06 display as ♥♦♣♠.  The Windows command prompt does the same, for backwards compatibility, but Linux doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Linux systems typically use UTF-8 encoding, in which:

- ♠ = U+2660 = "\xE2\x99\xA0"
- ♣ = U+2663 = "\xE2\x99\xA3"
- ♥ = U+2665 = "\xE2\x99\xA5"
- ♦ = U+2666 = "\xE2\x99\xA6"

**Edit:** Unfortunately, the *Windows* command prompt doesn't support UTF-8, but uses the old DOS code pages.  If you want your program to work cross-platform, you'll have to do something like:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__MSDOS__)
   #define SPADE   "\x06"
   #define CLUB    "\x05"
   #define HEART   "\x03"
   #define DIAMOND "\x04"
#else
   #define SPADE   "\xE2\x99\xA0"
   #define CLUB    "\xE2\x99\xA3"
   #define HEART   "\xE2\x99\xA5"
   #define DIAMOND "\xE2\x99\xA6"
#endif
```

Comment: do you know if i need to include anything or define anything in visual studio for them to show? I can't seem to get the symbols to work (They show the same as when i use \x03

Comment: No need to do the UTF-8 encoding manually. GCC also understands `"\u2660"` just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Characters like `'\x03` are *control characters*. `\x03` in particular is the character you get when you type Control-C (though typing that character often has other effects).

Some fonts happen to assign images to control character. As far as I know, there's no standard for doing so. Apparently in your previous configuration, some of the control character happened to be displayed as playing card suit symbols.

There are standard Unicode characters for those symbols:

```
2660  BLACK SPADE SUIT
2661  WHITE HEART SUIT
2662  WHITE DIAMOND SUIT
2663  BLACK CLUB SUIT
2664  WHITE SPADE SUIT
2665  BLACK HEART SUIT
2666  BLACK DIAMOND SUIT
2667  WHITE CLUB SUIT
```

(The numbers are in hexadecimal.)

Different systems encode Unicode in different ways. Windows usually uses some form of UTF-16. Linux usually uses UTF-8, but you can vary that by setting the locale.

Comment: Do you know if i have to define or include something in Visual studio? I get '?' instead of the werid symbols I used to get before now when using '2660'

Comment: @Seung: I don't use Visual Studio much, but how exactly are you using '2660'? If you mean literally `'2660'`, that's a multi-character constant with an implementation-defined (and probably useless) value. You probably want something like `L'\x2660'`, but getting it to print correctly might require something Windows-specific.

Answer (score 0):

If your Linux terminal character set is set to UTF-8, as it usually is, then you should be able to display all of the Unicode glyphs you have fonts for. Suit symbols are in the neighborhood of \u2660.

```
printf("A\u2660");
```

Should print "A" and the spade symbol, for example.

Comment: Would you happen to know if there's a way to put that in an array? Like in my char symbols[52] = {?}

Comment: Why not? It would have to be an array of strings, not characters, because the UTF-8 encoding for each of these symbols is three bytes long.

Comment: Since I just started programming I might be wrong but would it won't let me change it from ' ' to " "
for example, i currently have char symbols[52] = '\x03'
Changing it to char symbols[52] = {"\u2660".....} marks me an error

Comment: Of course, because '\x03' is a character literal, and "\u2660" is a string. You need to change symbols to `char *symbols[52] = { "...`, and then change things like %c to %s in printf lines.

Comment: Hmm that's weird, it actually did print me the first value but then the program just breaks out. I changed all the %c to %s in all the printf lines but strangely it sitll crashes it
this appearsUnhandled exception at 0x5244FB53 (msvcr120d.dll) in ProyectoPoker.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000068.

Comment: Well you still have to learn C programming. We can help with one thing at a time.

Comment: Would you happen to know why this happens? I'd like to research more about this problem to solve it since it seems your answer is the only one that actually prints it in visual studio and linux ._.

Comment: Can't diagnose code without seeing it. Isolate the error and open up another question.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux:

1. Verify that your locale is set to `<somelanguage>_<SOMEPLACE>.UTF-8` (type `locale` in the termunal).
2. Find a Unicode chart on the web. Verify that you can copy interesting characters with a mouse and paste them to the terninal.
3. Learn what UTF-8 is.
4. Write a program.
5. When it doesn't work, search this site using sonething like "how to print utf-8 in Linux". There are tons and tons of relevant answers. You want to call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` at the beginning of your program, as the language standard requires, and use `char`, not `wchar_t`.

On Windows:

1. Give up and cry. No, really.
2. Type `chcp 65001` in the console. No, really!
3. Set console fonts to Lucida. No, really!!!
4. Copy your Linux program over and compile and run it. (You do want to use the same program source on both OSes, right?) When it doesn't work, search for solutions online.
5. Go to 1.