# How can I print card suit characters in C Win32 console application?

Tags: c, special-characters

I have seen a few questions on how to print these characters but none of the methods appear to be working. I suspect it is because I making a Win32 console application based on some of the comments I read. 
Here is an example of what I have tried in my code currently. It only prints question mark boxes, or if I change it around I get question marks or random symbols.

I have tried defining these at the top.

```
#define SPADE '\x06'
#define CLUB  '\x05'
#define HEART '\x03'
#define DIAMOND '\x04'
```

inside function, these are some of the things I've tried. I have left S,D,H,C in case I can't figure it out.

```
    printf("%lc", SPADE);
    //printf("♠");
    //printf("S");

    printf("%lc", HEART);
    //printf("♥");
    //printf("H");

    printf("%lc", DIAMOND);
    //printf("♦");
    //printf("D");

    printf("%lc", CLUB);
    //printf("♣");
    //printf("C");
```

Comment: why do you think x06 is a spade character?

Comment: It prints question mark boxes because, the shell doesn't know which character to display for that hex value. You need to make sure you have a character pack installed which includes those characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print spades, hearts, diamonds, etc. in C and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133508/how-to-print-spades-hearts-diamonds-etc-in-c-and-linux)

Answer (score 1):

UTF-16 `wchar_t` and wide characters functions are needed in Windows.

```
#include <windows.h> 

int main()
{
    DWORD n;
    HANDLE hout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    const wchar_t *buf = L"♠♥♦♣\n";
    WriteConsoleW(hout, buf, wcslen(buf), &n, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The following code will compile with Visual Studio:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h> //for _setmode
#include <fcntl.h> //for _O_U16TEXT

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"♠♥♦♣\n");
    return 0;
}
```

After setting the mode to UTF-16, you have to call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_TEXT)` if you wish to use `printf` again.

Comment: Copy/pasting those characters ♠♥♦♣ into the Notepad++ text editor, saving, and looking at a file dump shows there are 3 bytes per glyph used, `E2 99 A0` and  `E2 99 A5` and `E2 99 A6` and `E2 99 A3`. That's 24 bits not 16.

Comment: @WeatherVane In Windows, when you copy the character it will be stored as UTF-16, when you paste in to Notepad++ it converts the format to UTF-8. Your *.cpp file is probably saved in UTF-8, but the compiler sees it as UTF-16 because of the `L` prefix in `L"♠♥♦♣\n"`. It can also print from Notepad++/MinGW whatever using `WriteConsoleW` see edit.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, these days I use MSVC compiler from console but do not use Visual Studio. The Notepad++ file was `.txt` so not used to compile. I realise the need to get up to speed with multi byte character encoding. But both of your examples when copy/pasted to a `.c` source code printed rubbish to the console. Are code pages still used?

Comment: @WeatherVane The only thing I can think of is that your Notepad++ file is not saved in UTF-8 (I thought it creates UTF-8 files by default). Double-check to make sure. I tried this with Notepad++/MinGW it worked. The wide char functions do not use code page.

Comment: Thank you Notepad++ does have such options I will check them out, previously left to default.

Comment: @Weather Vane I was able to recreate this problem in Notepad++ and Visual Studio. Evidently VS expects a UTF-8 BOM marker. I fixed this by running Notepad (Windows' Notepad) and saving that file in UTF-8 which forces BOM marker (gcc is not fussy like this)

Comment: Thanks but I avoid Windows Notepad wherever possible.

Comment: In Notepad++ set Encoding to UTF-8, and not ("UTF-8 without BOM")